# Problema ao adicionar elementos no array

Tags: java

Estou tentando adicionar elementos dentro do Array através de um método, porém, no final da execução ele repete o ultimo valor inserido. Fiz um código simples apenas para mostrar o erro e tentar evitar esse problema em atividades mais complexas no futuro.

```
public class Teste {
public String lista[] = new String[2];

public void adicionar(String nome) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        lista[i] = nome;
    }
}

public void mostrar() {

    for (String nome : lista) {
        System.out.println("Nome " + nome);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Teste teste = new Teste();
    teste.adicionar("Paulo");
    teste.adicionar("João");
    teste.mostrar();

}
```

[image: Imagem da execução]

Comment: O método `adicionar` sempre muda o valor de todos os elementos do array...

Comment: No método `adicionar()` aqui `for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {lista[i] = nome;}` você está instruindo que primeiro elemento de `lista` ao último receba `nome`. Use um [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) no lugar do Array.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que no método `adicionar` você percorre o campo `lista` preenchendo com a `String` passada como parâmetro, então quando o método é chamado pela segunda vez sobrescreve o que estava nas primeiras posições. Pode-se alterar esse comportamento verificando se o índice em questão está vazio e só assim preenchê-lo. Depois de preenchido, interrompe-se o laço:

```
// ...

public void adicionar(String nome) {
  for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    if (lista[i] == null) {
      lista[i] = nome;
      break;
    }
  }
}

// ...
```

---

Caso você não tenha restrição em apenas usar `array`, te aconselho a usar um `HashSet` para guardar os valores, simplificando seu código:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Teste {

  public HashSet<String> lista = new LinkedHashSet();

  public void adicionar(String nome) {
    lista.add(nome);
  }

  public void mostrar() {
    for (String nome : lista) {
      System.out.println("Nome " + nome);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Teste teste = new Teste();
    teste.adicionar("Paulo");
    teste.adicionar("João");
    teste.mostrar();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se quer mesmo usar um array, o jeito é você controlar a posição em que deve ser inserido o próximo (tomando o cuidado de não ultrapassar o tamanho do array). Algo assim:

```
public class Teste {
    private String lista[] = new String[2];
    private int adicionados = 0; // conta quantos foram adicionados

    public void adicionar(String nome) {
        if (this.adicionados == this.lista.length) { // já lotou o array
            System.out.println("não é possível adicionar mais nomes");
        } else { // ainda tem espaço
            this.lista[this.adicionados] = nome;
            this.adicionados++;
        }
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.adicionados; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nome " + this.lista[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, você não precisa fazer um *loop* para inserir (procurando algum espaço, até encontrar, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/496468/112052)), pois basta colocar o nome na posição correta. Tudo bem que nesse caso o array é pequeno, mas para arrays maiores isso se torna impraticável (e para que percorrer tudo de novo se eu já sei que as primeiras posições estarão ocupadas? não faz sentido).

A diferença é que para mostrar, você não pode fazer o *loop* por todo o array, e sim até a quantidade de nomes que foram inseridos. Assim você evita imprimir um monte de `null` (pois ao inicializar o array com `new String[2]`, os valores dele são setados para `null`).

---

Dito isso, se quer adicionar nomes "à vontade", sem se preocupar com o tamanho, pode usar uma lista:

```
public class Teste {
    private List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public void adicionar(String nome) {
        this.lista.add(nome);
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        for (String nome : this.lista) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
        }
    }
}
```

Ou, se quiser limitar a quantidade máxima de nomes que pode ter na lista:

```
public void adicionar(String nome) {
    if (this.lista.size() == 10) { // supondo que só pode ter 10 no máximo
        System.out.println("não é possível adicionar mais nomes");
    } else { // ainda tem espaço
        this.lista.add(nome);
    }
}
```

A outra resposta sugeriu usar `LinkedHashSet`, que também funciona. A diferença é que o `Set` não permite elementos repetidos, enquanto o `List` permite (veja o que faz mais sentido para o seu caso).